# On running an aggregate command, error message displayed: "Dataset byQuarter has no data"

Tags: syntax, spss

This is the code:

```
     COMPUTE Quarter=TRUNC((MONTH_-1)/3)+1. 
     EXECUTE.        
     DELETE VARIABLES MONTH_ DATE_.
     DATASET NAME KV. 
     DATASET DECLARE byQuarter. 
     AGGREGATE /OUTFILE='byQuarter' /BREAK=YEAR_ Quarter /KV.1 TO KV.126=MEAN(KV.1 TO KV.126). 
     DATASET ACTIVATE byQuarter.
```

There is no select case before this code. Can someone help with this error?

Comment: Your `BREAK` variable has a space in its name.
But the main problem is that AGGREGATE does not work the way you want it to. Are you sure you want to create 126 new variables, which would hold the means for the existing 126 variables ? What is your end goal ? Maybe there are easier ways to achieve your goal

Comment: Are you sure you have 126 KV variables...? Your code should be working...

Comment: @user10579790, the code seems good and should work. Please try to run the code on a small sample of data that you can post here. Usually working on that will reveal the problem already, if not, working with an example will enable us to help you more.

Comment: Hi, the code functions, seems there was an extra variable that i did not realize. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AGGREGATE /OUTFILE='byQuarter' /BREAK=YEAR_ Quarter
/KV.1_mean=MEAN(KV.1)
/KV.2_mean=MEAN(KV.2)
/KV.3_mean=MEAN(KV.3)
/KV.4_mean=MEAN(KV.4)
/KV.5_mean=MEAN(KV.5)
...
```

Comment: Hey, now I am getting two Errors: `>Error # 10934 in column 39.  Text: YEAR_Quarter 
>The AGGREGATE command specifies an unknown existing variable name. 
>Execution of this command stops. 
 
>Error # 10921 in column 169.  Text: ) 
>The number of existing variables does not match the number of new variables in 
>a new variable definition on the AGGREGATE command.`

Comment: edited my post, once I understood what you are after. please check now

Comment: From what I understand, `YEAR_` and `quarter` are two separate variables in the OP's original dataset.

Comment: which makes sense, considering the OP is referencing `MONTH_` and `DATE_`... Did not spot that, thank you